# Weird behaviour of bit-shifting with byte in Java

Tags: java, byte, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, binary-operators

As I was using bit-shifting on `byte`, I notice I was getting weird results when using unsigned right shift (`>>>`). With `int`, both right shift (signed:`>>` and unsigned:`>>>`) behave as expected:

```
    int min1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE>>31; //min1 = -1
    int min2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE>>>31; //min2 = 1
```

But when I do the same with `byte`, strange things happen with unsigned right shift:

```
    byte b1 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; //b1 = -128
    b1 >>= 7; //b1 = -1

    byte b2 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; //b2 = -128
    b2 >>>= 7; //b2 = -1; NOT 1!
    b2 >>>= 8; //b2 = -1; NOT 0!
```

I figured that it could be that the compiler is converting the `byte` to `int` internally, but does not seem quite sufficient to explain that behaviour.

**Why is bit-shifting behaving that way with byte in Java?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens exactly because `byte` is [promoted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1-100-C) to `int` prior performing bitwise operations. `int -128` is presented as:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

Thus, shifting right to 7 or 8 bits still leaves 7-th bit 1, so result is [narrowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3-220) to negative `byte` value.

Compare:

```
System.out.println((byte) (b >>> 7));           // -1
System.out.println((byte) ((b & 0xFF) >>> 7));  //  1
```

By `b & 0xFF`, all highest bits are cleared prior shift, so result is produced as expected.

Comment: Using `0xFF` is the correct solution. +1. Don't know why I didn't suggest that.

Comment: Did it not occur to them that this is an insane way to do things?

Answer (score 3):

Shift operators for `byte`, `short` and `char` are always done on `int`.

Therefore, the value really being shifted is the `int` value `-128`, which looks like this

```
int b = 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_10000000;
```

When you do `b2 >>= 7;` what you are really doing is shifting the above value 7 places to the right, then casting back to a `byte` by only considering the last 8 bits.

After shifting 7 places to the right we get

```
        0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111;
```

When we convert this back to a byte, we get just `11111111`, which is `-1`, because the `byte` type is signed.

If you want to get the answer 1 you could shift 31 places without sign extension.

```
byte b2 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; //b2 = -128
b2 >>>= 31;
System.out.println(b2);   // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [JLS 15.19 Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately.

and in [5.6.1 Unary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) :

> if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion

So, your `byte` operands are promoted to `int` before shifting. The value `-128` is `11111111111111111111111110000000` .

After the shifting 7 or 8 times, the lowest 8 bits are all 1s, which when assigning to a `byte`, a narrowing primitive conversion occurs. Refer to [JLS 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) :

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the *n* lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T.